# Al intentar arrancar MySQL, aparece No se estableció la conexión: los parámetros están incorrectos. mysqli_real_connect(): No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Descargué e instalé xampp; MySql database no arranca, y cuando ingreso a phpmyadmin recibo este error

> Error
> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
> No se estableció la conexión: los parámetros están incorrectos.
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
> La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
> phpMyAdmin intentó conectarse con el servidor MySQL, y el servidor rechazó esta conexión. Deberá revisar el host, nombre de usuario y contraseña en config.inc.php y asegurarse que corresponden con la información provista por el administrador del servidor MySQL.

Este mismo error me salía cuando usé mamp.

Comment: Especificaste alguna contraseña a PHPMyAdmin a la hora de crear la instalación de xampp? O dejaste el user "root" y sin passw por defecto?

Comment: lo deje sin pasword

Comment: Hola @mzygraphics, he visto que has dicho que tienes instalado little snicht. Es posible que te esté dando algún tipo de conflicto. Antes de probar mas cosas intentaría desinstalarlo y volver a reinstalar xampp a ver si así solucionamos el problema. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Intenta editar este archivo C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php busca esta variable:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Editalo y pon esto:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3306';
```

Lo que harias es añadir el puerto. No deberias de tener problemas con eso.

Comment: Hola gracias lo intente pero aun así no me funciono,sera que utilizo  el little snicht? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Haz una cosa, para el xampp (por si acaso) comprueba con netstat comprueba que puertos estas usando, con el comando;

```
netstat –ab
```

en caso de que te aparezca el puerto 3306 es que ese puerto ya esta siendo utilizado y no puedes usarlo para descartar el problema.

otra solución seria intentar instalarlo como servicio y reiniciar el equipo, sino también cabe comprobar que antes de "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] " no hay '//' si fuera el caso, elimínalo y comprueba

Answer (score 1):

tenía un problema parecido y es que cuando iniciaba MySQL desde Xampp me decía que no se podía establecer conexión y que los parámetros eran incorrectos.

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[image: Pantallazo del mensaje de error]

El problema se solucionó con la respuesta de @DiesanRomero

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

en mi caso el servidor de mariadb se encontraba detenido, ejecute:

```
#systemctl start mariadb
```

y el problema se soluciono.

Comment: No coloques un enlace como _clickbait_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.